# Passing a scriptblock through pipeline

Tags: powershell

Can I pass a scriptblock through the pipeline? For example, instead of

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Get-Job}
```

Can I do (conceptually) the following?

```
{Get-Job} | Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $_
```

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you running, and what operating system, by the way? Certain things like `$PSItem` are only available in PowerShell v3.0 and later.

Comment: OS: Windows 8.1, Posh: v4.0

Comment: Perfect, that's what I tested the code in my answer on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can. `$_` (aka `$PSItem`) isn't valid outside of something such as `ForEach-Object` or `Where-Object` though. So you'd have to do this:

```
# % is the default alias (short-hand) for ForEach-Object
{ Get-Process } | % { Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $_; };
```

You can also pass an array of `$ScriptBlock` objects, like this:

```
{ Get-Process }, { Start-Sleep -Seconds 2 }, { Get-ChildItem } | ForEach-Object -Process { Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $PSItem; };
```

Notice how the preceding code:

1. Gets a list of processes
2. Sleeps for two (2) seconds
3. Gets a list of child items under the current path

The `-Process` parameter on `ForEach-Object` is the "first" parameter, so normally you don't have to specify the parameter's name. I did specify the full `ForEach-Object` cmdlet name and added the `-Process` parameter name in the second example for the sake of clarity.

Here is an example where we declare an `Array` of `ScriptBlock` objects. Then, we pipe the array variable, containing the `ScriptBlock` objects into `ForEach-Object`. It's the same idea as above, but declaring the array separately. Remember though, if you're using `ForEach-Object`, you **must** use the `-Process` parameter, not the `-Begin` or `-End` parameters, because those only run **once** per call to `ForEach-Object`.

```
$ScriptBlockList = @(
    { Get-Process; };
    { Start-Sleep -Seconds 5; };
    { Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Get-Process; }; };
    );

$ScriptBlockList | ForEach-Object -Process { Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $PSItem; };
```

Comment: It worked great. Thanks for the second example as well - being able to pass multiple scriptblocks will be very useful.

Comment: Cool - glad to hear it helped you out. Cheers