# powershell -C measure-command with quoted strings where manual escaping isn't possible

Tags: powershell

I am trying to time commands that are coming out of a build system with the windows powershell meansure-command.  Many of the commands I want to time fail when used in this context and the failures indicate problems with quoting.  Some of the resources I have seen indicate that I should be escaping the quotes in these strings, but I don't know of a good way to do this in an automated context.

Some other sources indicate that I can somehow pipe a command into standard input and have this be executed.  I am assuming that this would avoid the need for escaping the quotes, but I am having trouble getting this to work.

As a test example, I am trying the following:

```
echo dir | powershell -C measure-command
```

> Measure-Command : Cannot bind parameter 'Expression'. Cannot convert the "dir " value of type "System.String" to type
>   "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + measure-command
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Measure-Command], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MeasureCommandCommand

It seems like a batch file would be an alternative here, but I would prefer a more direct method to avoid confounding my timing results.  What would be the best way to time these commands that have quotes in them?

Comment: You are a bit mystical about the commands to time. AFAIK `Measue-command` needs to frame the commands to measure in a `{script block}`

Comment: The commands I would like to execute come from a build system.  I can add the text of the command to something in powershell i.e. powershell -C measure-command { command-text }, but this loses the quotes from my command-text.  Alternatively I can save the command-text to a file.  I was hoping I could somehow pipe the text from this file into powershell to execute.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. But it is not the problem of dir function.
The problem is to transfert a parameter to powershell.exe.

In fact, when you send a parameter to powershell.exe like `myObject | powershell -C exec` , the argument is transform in String.

In your case,
if you load powershell and you send your command >

```
PS C:\Users\pierre> $foo = { dir }
PS C:\Users\pierre> Measure-Command $foo
```

You will have the result:

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 35
Ticks             : 350872
TotalDays         : 4,06101851851852E-07
TotalHours        : 9,74644444444444E-06
TotalMinutes      : 0,000584786666666667
TotalSeconds      : 0,0350872
TotalMilliseconds : 35,0872
```

$foo is a ScriptBlock Object

If you use the interactive parameter transfert, like

```
myObject | PowerShell -C [...]
```

It is not an object, it's a string.

It is like `Measure-Command $foo.ToString()`
And you have the same result

```
PS C:\Users\pierre> Measure-Command $foo.ToString()
Measure-Command : Impossible de lier le paramètre «Expression». Impossible de convertir la valeur « dir » du type «
System.String» en type «System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock».
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 17
+ Measure-Command $foo.ToString()
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument : (:) [Measure-Command], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MeasureCommandCommand
```

**The real question is "*How can I pass an Object for PowerShell.exe by PipeLine ?*"**

Use another help : [Passing a scriptblock through pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850655/passing-a-scriptblock-through-pipeline)

For this exemple, the question is "*Can we workaround the pipeline ?*".
At now, like this, the result can be printed (from command.exe or powershell.exe gui):

```
C:\Users\pierre>powershell -C "Measure-Command { echo dir }"
```

Delivery:

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 262
Ticks             : 2627527
TotalDays         : 3,04111921296296E-06
TotalHours        : 7,29868611111111E-05
TotalMinutes      : 0,00437921166666667
TotalSeconds      : 0,2627527
TotalMilliseconds : 262,7527
```

***By Generalization***

In Command.exe

```
C:\Users\pierre>set bar="echo dir"

C:\Users\pierre>echo %bar%
"echo dir"

C:\Users\pierre>powershell -C "Measure-Command { %bar% }"


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 22
Ticks             : 228750
TotalDays         : 2,64756944444444E-07
TotalHours        : 6,35416666666667E-06
TotalMinutes      : 0,00038125
TotalSeconds      : 0,022875
TotalMilliseconds : 22,875
```

In PowerShell.exe:

```
PS C:\Users\pierre> $bar = "echo dir"
PS C:\Users\pierre> $bar
echo dir
PS C:\Users\pierre> powershell -C "Measure-Command { ${bar} }"


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 16
Ticks             : 166117
TotalDays         : 1,92265046296296E-07
TotalHours        : 4,61436111111111E-06
TotalMinutes      : 0,000276861666666667
TotalSeconds      : 0,0166117
TotalMilliseconds : 16,6117
```

Best Regards,
Peter

Comment: There seem to be a few alternatives here, but my problem doesn't quite make it to the starting point for any of these.  I am starting from windows and have the ability to add my command-text to some windows command (this way would be easy except for the quotes) or I have the ability to save my command-text to a file and pipe the contents of this file into powershell.

Comment: You are right, it is not the real answer. But if you want to use the Pipe if your are into powershell, don't call a second time "powershell.exe -C". You use this practice because the needed object you want to use "Measure-Command" can not accept the pipeline argument. I thinks, for this case, it is not possible.PS C:\Users\pierre> man Measure-Command

NOM
    Measure-Command

SYNTAXE
    Measure-Command [-Expression] <scriptblock>  [<CommonParameters>]